# c# How to find UIElements in RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, rowdetailstemplate

I need to build the UIElementCollection DetailsElement, after initializing the UserControl.
My problem lies in the FindName. I can't figure out how to use the TemplatedParent. Which element is that? an how can I refer to it in CB?
So DetailsElements would contain all the InputField elements in the DataGrid Details.

```
public partial class Segments
{
    public Segments()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // this does not work
        var e = DgSections.FindName("MainPanel",...) as StackPanel;
        DetailsElements = e.Children;
    }

    UIElementCollection DetailsElements; 

    ...


<UserControl
    x:Class="My.Views.MainUserControls.Segments"
.....

<DataGrid
    x:Name="DgSections"
    ....
    <DataGrid.Columns>
     ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>  
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource DataGridDetailsBorder}">
                <StackPanel
                    x:Name="MainPanel"
                    ...>
                    <muc:InputField
                        x:Name="Length"
                         .../>

                    <muc:InputField
                        x:Name="Diam"
                        ... />   
                    // and more InputFields
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
   ....
```

Comment: MainPanel does not exist, until RowDetails are shown. Then DataTemplate gets loaded, and creates StackPanel and InputFields. There can be multiple instances of RowDetails and MainPanel. Please describe the purpose of getting MainPanel, there are likely better way to achive it. FYI,  RowDetails  binds to the same DataContext as DataGridRow

Comment: OK, then it is not possible to generate the list in the constructor and must I do it when the details are shown.
I need the list to set the visibility of the InputFields. They differ according to a ComboBox's SelectedItem in the Details themselves.

Comment: visibility can be changed via bindings

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, there is no `Border` element created by the time `Segments` is created. It's loaded and rendered on demand.

What you can do is to handle the `Loaded` event of the `Border` and programmatically set the properties of the `InputFields`:

```
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Border border = (Border)sender;
    StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)border.Child;
    foreach (InputField inputField in stackPanel.Children.OfType<InputField>())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Border Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource DataGridDetailsBorder}" Loaded="OnLoaded">
```